# how to increase the highlight area min and max value on drag in chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[image] I am using `react-chartjs-2` to draw the chart, right now I need to increase the highlight area min and max value on drag function is it possible? to highlight the graph, I am using `chartjs-plugin-annotation`, I tried with `chartjs-plugin-draggable` also it not working for me. if it is possible to give me with sample code?

my array

```
const highlightChart = [
      {
        drawTime: 'beforeDatasetsDraw',
        type: 'box',
        xScaleID: 'x-axis-0',
        yScaleID: 'y-axis-0',
        xMin: 0.019,
        xMax: 0.305,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(101, 33, 171, 0.5)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(101, 33, 171)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        draggable: true,
        onDrag: function(event) {
            console.log(event);
        }
      },
    ];

annotation: {
        drawTime: 'afterDraw',
        events: ['click'],
        annotations: highlightChart,
      },
```

Comment: any solution? for this

Comment: Post your code along with data.

Comment: @HassanImam thank u for reply sorry i am not having any sample data

Comment: @HassanImam is it possible?

Comment: I don't have any idea, I haven't worked much with chart.js. Please share the chart type you are using.

Comment: @HassanImam thank you for reply, chart type line

Comment: Is it possible to take the x-axis value on drag function?